# Does reputation have influence over how many views your post gets?

Tags: support, questions

I have a question on Stack Overflow here:
[iOS cordova-plugin-camera adds black backgound on PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52269413)

(feel free to check it out and answer if you can)

And when I posted the question, I thought it would have more views because of the question itself and the fact that the tags related to the question are all popular tags. Then I see questions get more views that have the same tags. The only difference is that the Questioners with a higher reputation, get more interaction than I would. Does reputation have influence over how many views your post gets?

Comment: to be honest (talking about my own experience) when I see a question posted by a high rep user I will for sure check it but no necessarely when it's a question from a new user (low rep) ... simply because I will have more luck to see a good quesiton from a high rep user than a low rep user

Comment: It is the question subject that discourages views.  The [ios] and [image] tag don't do anything useful.  The [cordova] tag, the one that really matters, has a badly broken community.  It never did well, but it has deteriorated significantly as of late.  Last week only 12% of the questions got an answer.

Comment: The popularity of the tags probably has something to do with it. Compare the <10k followers of [tag:cordova] with the 400k+ followers for each of Java, C++, PHP, JS, Python, etc. [tag:ios] has more, but it would be hard to be an expert in iOS as a whole.

Comment: I think high rep users are more likely to get upvoted on their posts (unless its blatantly low quality) which does increase the chances of their post getting more views. I see it with answers a lot too- a newer user posts an answer, a higher rep user posts a very similar answer a few minutes later- guess who gets upvoted and accepted answer. But looking at your tags a lot of the questions under those tags have no answer so it probably has to do more with that.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: for sure.  High rep users generally know how to find duplicates and solve their own problems in general, and know how to program.  (The few highish-rep users  that got most of it from posting really common questions are an exception.)  So if they have a question to ask, it's not going to be a run-of-the-mill beginner question with either an obvious answer (and usually a duplicate) or too many different things wrong to even answer.  *Most* questions suck.  You can tell a lot from the title, but a high-rep asker gets my attention.

Comment: @chevybow: yeah, I see that too.  The veteran user's answer is often at least better formatted, but usually also uses all the terminology more correctly, so it will usually sound slightly better to the veteran users in that tag.  If a newbie really does get everything right, I make sure to upvote though.  I try to make an effort to read more than just the first answer if I'm going to upvote anything on that page.  (If there's a better answer than the current accepted or highest, I don't want to make the gap wider on a question I'm not really interested in and didn't take the time to read.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's really the other way round.

95% of views come from web searches rather than people looking for answers within Stack Overflow itself. I suspect that those 95% neither know nor care much about reputation.

High rep users will have written high quality answers to get that rep in the first place though. Others outside Stack Overflow may link their blogs and other postings to such answers as well as attracting duplicates within Stack Overflow pointing to their answers, all of which encourages Search Engines to determine that when you search for an answer it's their answer that matches rather than some other less well written answer.

Cream rises to the top after all.

Comment: For views YES I have to agree. So for that I'd accpet this answer. @the google search stuff. But Stephen Leppik made a good point in his answer below too, actual interaction (commenting and answers) would come from StackOverflow users who may be more attracted to questions written by High Rep accounts.

Answer (score 13):

It has no *direct* effect. But if you have a lot of reputation points, people may take you more seriously, and you'll probably have a lot of experience writing good questions.

It is also kind of a chicken/egg thing: usually, writing high profile questions causes a lot of reputation points, not the other way around.

Answer (score 5):

When you first post a question all the views you get come from the Stack Overflow question stream. It is the question **title** that drives the first bunch of views.

Over time the question will move down the question list and views will drop off.

Getting up votes seems to slow the question drift down the list, and this gives it time to attract more views. Doing edits to the question and/or receiving answers can move the question back up the lists. You can also get flagged as a trending topic which drives a lot of traffic to your question.

When you tag your question with popular tags, then that question gets pushed down quickly on the tag lists, because new questions are coming in quickly. On the flip side if you tag with unpopular tags, then there aren't many viewers watching those tags.

Web search results will drive page views over the **life** of the question, but we want answers quickly and creating good questions with good titles is the key.

The positive rules of writing webpage titles for SEO also apply to Stack Overflow, and the negative rules also apply (i.e. click bait titles).

SEO reference: https://moz.com/learn/seo/title-tag